# Cognito authentication of a site made with react and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, amazon-cognito

I have to implement a web server, I have a backend with express.js and frontend with react. I need to manage authentication with AWS Cognito.

Nav component in React contains and  tag which takes me to the hosted ui

```
export default function Nav(){

    const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
    searchParams.get("code")
    console.log(useSearchParams)
    return(
        <Header>
            <logo><span>GREEN</span> ENERGY HOME</logo>
            <login href="https://my_domain.com/login?response_type=code&client_id=my_code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3001" >Login</login>
        </Header>
    )
}
```

since it's a web page I used the authorization code as a method.
Once logged in, it redirects me to the express sever "localhost:3001", I extract the auth code from the query parameters and send it to the token endpoint to receive the three tokens `(ACCESS_TOKEN, ID_TOKEN, REFRESH_TOKEN)`

```
app.get('/auth', async function (req, res){
    

    console.log('-------------')

    //take the value of authentication code in the request body
    const code = req.query.code;
    
    
    const token = await fetch('https://my_domain.com/oauth2/token', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        body:new URLSearchParams({
            "grant_type": process.env.AWS_COGNITO_GRANT_TYPE,
            "client_id": process.env.AWS_COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
            "client_secret": process.env.AWS_COGNITO_CLIENT_SECRET,
            "code": code,
            "redirect_uri":"http://localhost:3001/auth"
        })
    }).then((res) => {return res.json()}); 
    
    console.log("token: ");
    console.log(token);

    const ID_TOKEN = token.id_token;
    const ACCESS_TOKEN = token.access_token;
    const REFRESH_TOKEN = token.refresh_token;
    
    const id_cookie = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000000) + 1;
    setID_TOKEN.set(id_cookie, ACCESS_TOKEN)
    
    //console.log(setID_TOKEN)
    //res.send({body:id_cookie}).status(200);
    
    //res.status(200).send({token: ACCESS_TOKEN})
    //res.locals.loggato = "true";
    
    res.cookie('cookie',id_cookie);
    //res.json({Status: "Success"})
    res.send({Status: "Success" })    
    //res.redirect('http://localhost:3000');
    //res.send({body:"true"})   
})
```

Now since it's not a good idea to pass the token as a cookie, I was thinking of storing the token in a map along with a cookie id, and it works if you want. But my problem is that I don't know how to create authorization in react.

The thing I've tried is trying to send a Status as a response which, once I get to react, sets a state, but the problem I immediately encountered is that I don't have any fetch from which I can get the response.

Now my question is is there a way to make this work? Or am I doing something wrong? Grazie tante!